# Trying to learn and run a simple if-else-if script, but not getting results

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is the nested script I made and am trying to run:

```
    var coin = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
    var character = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
    if (character == 1) {
        //It's a kid
        if (coin == 0)   {
            alert("where'd the coin go?");
        }   else if (coin == 1) {
                alert("you got heads dude");
            }   else if (coin== 2) {
                    alert("you got tails dude");
                }
    }   else {
        //now it's a computer
        if (coin ==0) {
            alert("3RR0R C01N G0N3");
        }   else if (coin==1) {
                alert("H34D5");
            }   else if (coin==2) {
                    alert("T41L5");
        }
```

Sadly, nothing is showing up. Any suggestions?
edi-t updated with correct code formatting, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Have you looked in your browsers error console to see what it says?

Comment: I debugged it multiple times, but nothing showed up.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executed in the first place? It looks find to me apart from the fact that `coin` will always be 0 or 1, never 2.

Comment: As a sidenote, you'd better use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1` here.

Comment: thanks Rasmus, that was the thing missing!
Raina, is there a reason that is preferred over what I used? the floor command was what I was going to go with if I couldn't figure this one out, but it seems to work okay now that I closed the last else clause

Comment: You should accept Rasmus's answer, if did worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the last parenthesis:

```
var coin = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
    var character = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
    if (character == 1) {
        //It's a kid
        if (coin == 0)   {
            alert("where'd the coin go?");
        }   else if (coin == 1) {
                alert("you got heads dude");
            }   else if (coin== 2) {
                    alert("you got tails dude");
                }
    }   else {
        //now it's a computer
        if (coin ==0) {
            alert("3RR0R C01N G0N3");
        }   else if (coin==1) {
                alert("H34D5");
            }   else if (coin==2) {
                    alert("T41L5");
        }
    }
```

You should always check Console output of your browser when dealing with "mysterious" stuff like this!

Oh, and if you need a  simple JS console for trying code snipets - use [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a `}` to close the `else` statement.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mNUAD/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest `else` is not closed.